# Strange widget at the top of all apps

Tags: android

I download Tango App from [Play Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sgiggle.production).

And when I (for example) play game (or run any another app) and I revive new message from Tango app - I see strange widget at the top of the all apps. I can drag it, but active app doesn't lost focus.

I have one question: may be someone knows, HOW does they made such functionality?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It could be a custom Toast.

Comment: Toast, which I can drag?

Comment: Ah no, you're correct. I had missed the drag part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this tutorial

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

its basically a service with a view with an extra permission needed, based on facebook's chatheads idea

Comment: Yes, maybe this is it!